# python list from database table into a dictionary

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am  trying to change a list from table of items and there prices into dictionary for easily usage but still can't 
I wanna to be like name is key and price like value in dictionary form

this is the code that is reading from a database

```
def items():
    cur.execute("SELECT name,price FROM items")
    return cur.fetchall()
```

I need to split like this

```
 Items = {'mobile': 100.80,'projecter': 450.45,'canon': 350.65}
```

any help please

Answer (score 1):

The [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor accepts an iterable with `key, value` pairs and `cursor.fetchall()` produces exactly that, so all you need to do is just instantiate a `dict` with the returned result:

```
def items():
    cur.execute("SELECT name,price FROM items")
    return dict(cur.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
items = {}
for row in cur.fetchall():
    items[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Obviously, you have to select the right indices yourself when accessing the row tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this , Your result object will be like list of tuples or lists, since you want to two return two values you can try dict comprehension :

```
items = {row[0]:row[1] for row in cur.fetchall()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Items = {} 
for item in items():
    Items[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Sould do it as fetchall return a list of tuples and the tuples have the values in order.